# what is the difference between labels and exemplar in promethus?

Tags: prometheus

Label are used to identify or select metrics

Exemplar are also kv pairs to identify metrics

What is the diffenece? Why not just use the label ?

Answer (score 3):

[Exemplars](https://github.com/OpenObservability/OpenMetrics/blob/main/specification/OpenMetrics.md#exemplars) are data types which are used to create references to data outside of the [MetricSet](https://github.com/OpenObservability/OpenMetrics/blob/main/specification/OpenMetrics.md#metricset). So the assumption above that exemplars are for identifying metrics is not right rather it is for linking the metrics with external information (common use case is linking to the program traces) that will help SRE's/Engineers to debug faster.

For example, if you have exemplars setup within your metrics and if you are using [Tempo](https://github.com/grafana/tempo), then Grafana will give you the ability to directly open traces from your grafana panel. [example](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/fundamentals/exemplars/)

[Labels](https://github.com/OpenObservability/OpenMetrics/blob/main/specification/OpenMetrics.md#label) are another datatype, they are used to differentiate various characteristic within a [metric](https://prometheus.io/docs/tutorials/understanding_metric_types/#types-of-metrics).

Answer (score 0):

Exemplars are typically used to associate trace identifiers with metric data collected in a time interval, but they can be used to associate any non-metric data with the collected metrics. Storing trace information with the metric data lets you quickly identify the traces associated with a sudden change in metric values;
The following screenshot shows a Grafana chart of sets of histogram buckets and associated exemplars, with one exemplar expanded:

[image]

but label is another thing, Labels are key-value pairs associated with time series that, in addition to the metric name, uniquely identify them. That’s a bit of a mouthful, so let’s look at an example.
If you had a metric for HTTP requests that was broken out by path, you might try putting the path in the metric name, such as is common in Graphite:1

```
http_requests_login_total
http_requests_logout_total
http_requests_adduser_total
http_requests_comment_total
http_requests_view_total
```

These would be difficult for you to work with in PromQL. In order to calculate the total requests you would either need to know every possible HTTP path or do some form of potentially expensive matching across all metric names. Accordingly, this is an antipattern you should avoid. Instead, to handle this common use case, Prometheus has labels. In the preceding case you might use a path label:

```
http_requests_total{path="/login"}
http_requests_total{path="/logout"}
http_requests_total{path="/adduser"}
http_requests_total{path="/comment"}
http_requests_total{path="/view"}
```